# Error on installing packages on python

Tags: python, pip, package

I tried to install pandas on my cmd and this is the output

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.5.0 in c:\users\name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in c:\users\name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2018.4)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.0 in c:\users\name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.14.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas) (1.11.0)

**distributed 1.21.8 requires msgpack, which is not installed.**
```

This last line is in red.

Im on windows 10, I installed anaconda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work for me.
First I tried

```
pip install msgpack
```

And if you need this too,

```
pip install msgpack-python
```

Then install whatever you need. In your case,

```
conda install pandas
```

Answer (score 1):

You should install msgpack and then install pandas again.

Comment: How  can I install the msgpack?

Comment: Just like you install any other package.

Answer (score 0):

How are you installing pandas? If you're using Anaconda, then

```
conda install pandas
```

is typically enough to make everything work. This is because Anaconda is using binary installs - it is uploading prebuilt code and has already done the combinatorics to make everything work together - and it gets everything it needs for a package.

Sometimes, of course, you have to go into a dependency combination that is tough, or you are pulling from non-core Anaconda repos, etc. In that case, you can try

```
conda install msgpack
# or
pip install msgpack
# or
conda install -c conda-forge msgpack
```

The right choice sort of depends on what you're doing. Using the `-c` flag with `conda` gives you access to non-core repositories - these carry fewer guarantees about working together, but gives you access to many more versions of the package, usually.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting a similar error when trying to install pymc3. I solved it by using conda rather than pip.

The first time I used `pip install pymc3` and I got the same error as you:

```
distributed 1.21.8 requires msgpack, which is not installed
```

Then I installed using conda instead: `conda install pymc3`, and it installed fine.

My understanding is that conda handles all the dependent packages for you, which pip does not.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the Anaconda site:

Use anaconda to install msgpack for python with this command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge msgpack-python
```

It seems to have worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
conda install pip
pip uninstall -y msgpack-python
pip install msgpack
TCIP-scheduler
```

run these commands